# Can collection be used a verb? Eg. the activity of data collection over the activity of data collecting

Tags: verbs

I am writing a research paper about data collectors, but there is no existent terminology for the activity of such collectors. Would it be data collecting? Or data collection?

Example from my paper:

Data collecting/collection is defined as the large accumulation of data with a cohesive theme with the aim of enriching a personal collection.

Comment: Isn't the real question _Can 'collecting' be used as a true noun?_ or perhaps _Can 'collecting' be used as if it were a noun while remaining not a true noun?_? Compare 'rubbish collection' with 'refuse disposal'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It does and doesn't at the same time. Thank you, it is actually quite helpful. I may just have to stick with digital collection unless I am strictly referring to the act of collecting data. It seems to not work if the noun is in front.

Comment: Both are allowable. 'Data collecting' would be far less usual, but might be used when the actual mechanics of the collecting (knocking on doors? asking five yes-no questions? ...) was being discussed. The ing-form is the more 'verby', action/process-focused choice.